# Convergence of a binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have the binomial expansion $$1+(-1)(-2z)+\frac{(-1)(-2)(-2z)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-1)(-2)(-3)(-2z)^3}{3!}+...$$

Which simplifies down to $$1+2z+(-2z)^2+(-2z)^3$$

How do I find out if this binomial expansion converges for $|z|<1$?

Comment: Is 4th term surely, $+(-2z)^3$ and this seems like related to the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-2z}$ probably converge if this converges.

Comment: @mann is their an easier way to tell?

Comment: There is a sign error in the fourth term. You are looking at the series $1+2z+(2z)^2+(2z)^3+\cdots$. You can recognize this as a geometric series, which converges is $2|z|\lt 1$ and diverges otherwise. So there is convergence only for $|z|\lt 1/2$, the $|z|\lt 1$ is not correct.

Comment: @mann i think it is $-(-2z)^3$ because $-3*-2=6$ then $6*(-1)=-6$

Comment: Yes it is, and as @AndréNicolas stated is correct.

Comment: @Aljabra: I expect you were computing the Maclaurin-Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-2z}$.   How one determines the $z$ for which the series converges depends heavily on context, and how detailed one has to be. The most formal way is to find a formula for the sum $S_n(z)$ of the terms up to the $z^n$ term, and showing this has a limit as $n\to\infty$ precisely if $|2z|\lt 1$.

Comment: @andrenicolas   Is it possible to do it by inspection? Would you be so kind as to show me an example please?

Comment: It is possible to do it by quoting the result about when an infinite geometric series $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots$ converges. Or else you can use the Ratio Test, if that has been proved already.  (Although logically Ratio Test depends on behaviour of geometric series.)

Comment: @andresnicolas ok thanks